# jQuery.post and joomla pass upload field

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm currently developing one component for `joomla` and on the front end i need tu upload photo.... The php code for upload is ready... The problem is that i want to make the pic upload `onchange` of `file field` named logo but it says that there's no such entry(javascript does not pass the fieldvalue or something)
`Notice: Undefined index: logo in /var/www/furnish/components/com_furnishing/controller.php on line 21`

My javascript code is

```
jQuery(function(){
        console.info("ok"); 

        jQuery('input[name="logo"]').change(function(){
            var val=jQuery(this).val();
            var filename = jQuery('input[name="logo"]').val();
            //var forma = $(this);
            //
        //  jQuery('input[name="task"]').val('register.upload');
            console.log(filename);
             $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?option=com_furnishing&task=upload",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data:  jQuery('form[name="Form"]'),
                success: function (dati) {
                    alert("Data Uploaded: "+dati);
                }
            });/*
        jQuery('input[name="task"]').val('register.upload');
            jQuery.post('index.php?option=com_furnishing&task=upload',$("form[name='Form']"),function(data){
                if (data)
                {
                    jQuery('input[name="logo"]').val(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery('input[name="logo"]').val('');
                }
                alert(data);
                console.info(data);
            });
            jQuery('input[name="task"]').val('register.regme');*/
        console.info("ok");

        });
    });`
```

The part which is `commented out` has the same problem. So the question is how to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time i managed to figure this out. As one of the forums told that there is no way to post file field i managed to create a `jQuery` check which checks for the file size,type..... Beacose i needed to check for file type and size that was the fasstest and easyest way to do it.